# Validating multiple textboxes using errorprovider

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 10 textboxes, now i want to check that none of them are empty when a button is clicked.
 My code is :

```
 if (TextBox1.Text == "")
 {
    errorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "Please fill the required field");
 }
```

Is there any way that I can check all the textboxes at once, rather than writing for every individual?

Comment: That's almost certainly Windows Forms, not asp.net.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, there is.

First, you need to obtain all the text boxes in form of a sequence, for instance like this:

```
var boxes = Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

Then, you can iterate over them, and set the error accordingly:

```
foreach (var box in boxes)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(box.Text))
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(box, "Please fill the required field");
    }
}
```

I would recommend using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `x == ""` or + `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to mark text boxes filled with spaces, tabs and the like with an error.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be an optimal solution but this also should work

```
    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       textBox1.Validated += new EventHandler(textBox_Validated);
       textBox2.Validated += new EventHandler(textBox_Validated);
       textBox3.Validated += new EventHandler(textBox_Validated);
       ...
       textBox10.Validated += new EventHandler(textBox_Validated);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ValidateChildren();
    }

    public void textBox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        var tb = (TextBox)sender;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

```
var controls = new [] { tx1, tx2. ...., txt10 };
foreach(var control in controls.Where(e => String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text))
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(control, "Please fill the required field");
}
```