# Handle more than one error with a errorprovider

Tags: c#, error-handling

Can I handle more than one validation for (for example) 6 text-boxes with one error provider?

Comment: Yes there is Hamid Talebi, take a look at this StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129824/validating-multiple-textboxes-using-errorprovider

Comment: @DJKRAZE ,I saw it.But a question!in that way can I write a error text validation for every text box?For example:
var controls = new [] { tx1, tx2. ...., txt10 };
foreach(var control in controls.Where(e => String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text))
{
errorProvider1.SetError(contro1, "Please fill this");
errorProvider1.SetError(contro2, "Please fill the required field");
errorProvider1.SetError(contro3, "Please fill all");
}

Comment: can you add that code you put in your comment to your question..

Comment: Hamid Talebi, if you have the code does it make sense to ask a question about if something would work.. try out the example code you just posted..

Answer (score 0):

Example gives each textbox an error if its empty, and specifies which textbox the error is for.

*Edit with switch

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in Controls) { textBox.Validating += textBox1_Validating; }
}

private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ErrorProvider errProv = new ErrorProvider();
    TextBox txtSender = (TextBox)sender;
    string content = txtSender.Text;
    string error = "";

    switch (txtSender.Name)
    {
        case "textBox1":
            error = "error textbox1";
            break;
        case "textBox2":
            error = "error textbox2";
            break;
        case "textBox3":
            error = "error textbox3";
            break;
        case "textBox4":
            error = "error textbox4";
            break;
        case "textBox5":
            error = "error textbox5";
            break;
        case "textBox6":
            error = "error textbox6";
            break;
        case "textBox7":
            error = "error textbox7";
            break;
        case "textBox8":
            error = "error textbox8";
            break;
    }

    if (content == "") { errProv.SetError(txtSender, error); }
}
```

Comment: Can't you do that in a more efficient way.. also that's a lot of hard coding.. that code could be cut down using a foreach loop on Controls by the way..